# Using a SELECT Query to retrieve data from a database using a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, xampp

I want to use a SELECT Query to retrieve data from a database, that displays the list of categories and the number of DVDs in each category using a multidimensional array.

```
Table Name: dvds_table 
dv_id   dv_caid dv_name
1   4   Matrix Reloaded
2   2   Johnny English
3   4   The Recruit      
4   4   Minority Report     
5   3   Two Weeks Notice 
6   2   Bend It Like Beckham

Table Name: categories_table 
ca_id   ca_name
2   Comedy
4   Action
1   Drama
3   Romance
5   TV
```

This is what I've come up with so far, excuse my basic knowledge:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dvddb");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$categories=getNumDvdsInCategories();


function getNumDvdsInCategories() {


$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('categories_table');
$this->db->order_by('ca_name', 'DESC');

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}


$this->load->model("model");
$data['results'] = $this->model->list_categories();
$this->load->view('categories_list_view', $data);


?>

<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
            <td>Category ID</td>
            <td>Category Name</td>
            <td>Num. DVDs</td>
    </tr>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $category['ca_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category['ca_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $category['num']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Belief that this code will give the results you are looking for. Please Google for information about mysql COUNT which counts the number of rows in a selection, and LEFT JOIN which joins rows from two tables together in a selection.

I've tried to keep as much from the original code in tact. Only the query part has changed. I can advice you to read-up about the SQL.

You can play around with the AS aliases or removed them. Please note they will affect the $catetory key names. And maybe you want to remove the ID from the selection. But that's up to you.!

```
<?php
// * These where the create queries that I have used to make a similar table as you.
// create table dvds_table ( dv_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, dv_caid INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (dv_caid) references categories_table(ca_id), dv_name varchar(20));
// create table categories_table (ca_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ca_name varchar(20));

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dvddb');

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// * use $sql example below if you dont want the ID (Then also remove $category['ID'] in your HTML). 
// * Also you can remove the AS aliases or rename them as you see fit (then also change the $category key names).
// $sql = 'SELECT categories_table.ca_name AS Category, COUNT(dvds_table.dv_caid) AS Amount FROM categories_table LEFT JOIN dvds_table ON dvds_table.dv_caid = categories_table.ca_id GROUP BY categories_table.ca_name ORDER BY categories_table.ca_name DESC;';

$sql = 'SELECT  categories_table.ca_id AS ID,
            categories_table.ca_name AS Category,
            COUNT(dvds_table.dv_caid) AS Amount
            FROM categories_table
            LEFT JOIN dvds_table
            ON dvds_table.dv_caid = categories_table.ca_id
            GROUP BY categories_table.ca_id
            ORDER BY categories_table.ca_name DESC;';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

?>

<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Category ID</td>
        <td>Category Name</td>
        <td>Num. DVDs</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($result as $category) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $category['ID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category['Category']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category['Amount']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>

<?php
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Malcom that produces the correct results, however I'm stuck on using the getNumDvdsInCategories() function to query the database and return a multidimensional array. 

p.s. I defiantly need to read up on sql!

Comment: @dillydingdillydong I don't understand why you are stuck on using the getNumDvdsInCatageries() function? Just use my code as is, or reconfigure it to your liking! And if you like my answer, can you please mark it as the answer? Or else specify more information about what would be a better answer?